# Clang error when compiling in CodeRunner

Tags: macos, clang

I've used CodeRunner (http://krillapps.com/coderunner) for a long time but recently I can't compile any Objective-C code in it. I think this started happening around the time I updated to Xcode 5.1. I can still compile and run as normal in Xcode.

When I try to run in CodeRunner, the following error is printed.

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-finput-charset=UTF-8' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
```

I've tried searching for what this error means but I can't find much. Has anyone got any ideas of what this might be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Open Preferences
- Click Edit script (frist screenshot)
- Second screenshot: Remove the param at I. line should look like II.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any idea as to what the problem was?

Comment: Actually what the output says, after updating XCode clang treated unknown params as errors, which stopped compilation. This param must have been in there for a long time unnoticed.