# Clang error when compiling C++/C code in CodeRunner

Tags: c++, c, xcode

I've used CodeRunner (http://krillapps.com/coderunner) for a long time but recently I can't compile any C or C++ code in it. This started happening around the time I updated to Xcode 5.1. I can still compile and run as normal in Xcode.

When I try to run in CodeRunner, the following error is printed.

clang: error: unknown argument: '-finput-charset=UTF-8' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

There is already a solution for Objective C:
[Clang error when compiling in CodeRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750345/clang-error-when-compiling-in-coderunner/23104434#23104434)

Does anyone know how to modify the script for C++/ C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to the compilation settings in in coderunner and remove that command line flag. it looks like clang doesn't use it any more (or it might have been replaced with a different flag. check the clang manpage for more info on these flags)

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar bug with the object-c compilation, the link to fix that is

[Clang error when compiling in CodeRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750345/clang-error-when-compiling-in-coderunner),

and you just need do as below for the c/c++ situation:

## g++ "$1" -o "$compname" -finput-charset=${enc[$2]} $3

g++ "$1" -o "$compname" $3